# is the condition satisfied for the given ultrafilter

Tags: general-topology

Let $U$ be an ultrafilter on $X$. Does $\{ x(i)\} \in U$ imply $U= U(x(i))= \{ F \subseteq X \mid x(i)\in F\}\text{?}$
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where you wrote { F subset of X l x(i)€ F}, it seemed plausible that you meant $\{ F \subseteq X \mid x(i)\in F\}$ and I edited accordingly.

Comment: Yes you r right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's recall the filter axioms for a filter $U$:

1. If $F,G \in U$, then $F \cap G \in U$.
2. $\emptyset \notin U$.
3. If $F \in U$ and $F \subseteq B \subseteq X$, then $B \in U$.

If $\{p\} \in U$ for some $p \in X$, then $U = \{F \subseteq X \mid p \in U \}$, indeed:

If $A \in U$, then $A \cap \{p\} \neq \emptyset$ by axioms 1. and 2. This means that $p \in A$, so $A$ is the right hand set.

OTOH, if $p \in F \subseteq X$, then $\{p\} \subseteq F$ so that axiom 3. implies $p \in U$. So the other inclusion also holds.

Comment: How can you say that all memebers of U must intersect {x(i)} .

Comment: I only know the theorem,

Comment: That if U is a filter and A is a non empty subset of X such that A intersects each F€ U then A€U .

Comment: @mathisfun filter axiom: if $A,B \in U$ then $A\cap B \in U$. Also $\emptyset \notin U$ is another filter axiom.

Comment: You don't need the ultrafilter characterization you mention.

Comment: Your writing is not clear 2nd line what is cap?

Comment: Will you please write the complete proof of the 2nd line..It is getting twisted for me..otherwise everythinh is fine

Comment: Yeah I have got it thanks a lot

Comment: @mathisfun the enlargement referred to the filter axiom: if $A\in U$ and we have for any $B\subseteq X$ that $A\subseteq B$, then $B\in U$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes U is the principle ultrafilter generated by a singleton, namely {x(i)}.